# CurrentScreenVideo function

Tags: front-end, notebooks, kernel, video

Does anybody know if Wolfram is looking into creating a function that can record you screen video.
Preferably regions AND active windows and such so I don't have to buy additional software to do that.
Perhaps off topic but sometimes I see short video's/animations etc. showing content in a notebook. What software is used there at this moment.
Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was added in 12.3:

```
screen = VideoRecord["Screen"]
```

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VideoRecord.html

See examples under Scope - Section.

Comment: Well I be damned.. Couldn't find it.. I should stop working for today but thx for the quick reply! It looks great. Will start playing with it!

Comment: Doesn't work with 2 screens using a NotebookObject as target on Windows. Works with 1 screen.